# Modified convection diffusion reaction equations

Tags: finite-element

I am trying to solve convection diffusion type equations by a modification:
$$-\epsilon \Delta u+ b \nabla u+cu=f_1,$$
with the following boundary conditions:
$$u=g~ on ~\Gamma_D,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \epsilon \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g_N ~~on ~~\Gamma_N.$$

The idea is  to solve another equation:
$$-\nu\Delta u+ \nabla u+\frac{c}{b}u=f_2,$$
$$u=g~ on ~\Gamma_D,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \epsilon \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g_N ~~on ~~\Gamma_N.$$

where $\nu=\frac{\epsilon}{b}$ 
and then use $\nu+\delta$ instead of $\nu.$ 
so we should solve
$$$$
$$-(\nu+ \delta) \Delta u+ \nabla u+\frac{c}{b}u=f_3,$$
$$u=g~ on ~\Gamma_D,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \epsilon \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g_N ~~on ~~\Gamma_N.$$
Here
$(\nu+\delta)=\frac{h}{2}*coth(\frac{h}{2*\nu})$, where $h$ is the mesh size.

Now the question is that what the relations are between $f_1,f_2,f_3.$ I used $f_2=f_3$ and $f_2=\frac{f_1}{b}$. Is it true?

Also if $b$ be a vector I used $||b||_\infty$, but the results are acceptable just for some examples. Am I wrong in this way?

Comment: Err, you can't divide by a vector. If you divide by $\|b\|_\infty$, then the second term still looks like $\frac{b}{\|b\|_\infty }\cdot \nabla u$ which is still a directional derivative.

Comment: Similarly, what do you mean by "where $\nu=...$ and then use $\nu+\delta$ instead of $\nu$"? Why would you do this?

Comment: I wanted to use $\nu+\delta$ for stabilization of the convection diffusion, for increasing Peclet number. But this method does not work for one of my examples. I had to use $\nu+h/2$ instead of $\nu$. In fact  using $h/2 \Delta u$ as an artificial  diffusion.

Comment: Well, but you still haven't answered my first question.

Comment: First, thank you so much for your first comment. By this I edited my program and now the results are too similar. But for the second, sorry I really do not understand your question, as I said before it got from dividing the coefficient of diffusion by advection coefficient.

Comment: I don't see what you edited, but at the very least, it didn't get any better: you just can't divide by a vector.